# How to source a variable from script into shell without executing the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have the below bash script:

```
FILES="file_1 file_2 \
file_3"
export FILES
run_test
```

It has a FILES variable that is written on multiple lines and then the script calls another script.

I want to source the script to have the variable FILES defined in the shell but without calling the other script "run_test"

I tried to grep the FILES variable from script but it gets the first line only in the variable.

Any recommendations please?

Comment: My recommendation is to rewrite the sourced script to e.g. take a flag or variable to skip the commands you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You might want the consider an `env.sourceme` file with shared settings like `FILES=`.
This file can be sourced by both your original and your new script.

When you don't want/can change the original file, you need to do something else.
When your `sed` supports `-z` you can use

```
source <(sed -rz 's/.*(FILES="[^"]*").*/\1/' inputscript)
```

You can use `grep` when you parse the inputscript first:

```
source <(tr "\n" "\r" < inputscript | grep -Eo 'FILES="[^"]*"' | tr "\r" "\n")
```